# Can I stop Apple Watch Now Playing App from defaulting to the watch as the source?

Tags: iphone, audio, apple-watch, watchos

Sometime recently the Apple Watch's Now Playing app has switched to showing the watch as the default source. I rarely to never play anything from my watch and just want to use Now Playing to control my phone. This means I have to bring up Now Playing and then select the phone before I can use the audio controls on the watch.

I've tried restarting my phone and watch, re-pairing the watch, and even deleted and reinstalled Now Playing on the watch.

Reinstalling seemed to fix it, but just now it went back to the watch when I brought the app up.

Really I'd like it to just go to the phone if that is the only thing playing (since that is basically always what is happening when I use the app)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this may have been a bug fixed in 9.5.1

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/337774)

Comment: Hey hey! I’m the question author 

Comment: Sorry!  It happens sometimes.